# Snowflake cursor fetch_arrow_all returns 1816 date

Tags: python, timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, pyarrow

I have a use case where I need to fetch snowflake response as pyarrow table using fetch_arrow_all. The date which are like 9999-10-10 getting defaulted to 1815/1816.

```
cursor.execute("select TO_TIMESTAMP('9999-01-01T00:00:59') as d1 from table(generator(rowcount => 100)) UNION ALL select TO_TIMESTAMP('9999-01-01T00:00:59') as d1").fetch_arrow_all().to_pandas()
```

Could you please help resolving this?

Comment: did you try ```to_pandas(timestamp_as_object=True)```?